# Checkbox treeview not checked in react

Tags: reactjs, treeview

I have followed below example to create a treeview checkbox.

[example](https://github.com/jakezatecky/react-checkbox-tree)

Its using extends component. But My code i need to use a class. So i have created and data also loading no issue. But when i tried to onchecked its not working.

```
const stateLod = {
    checked: [],
    expanded: [],
    data : [],  
    setDataLoad:null
}
```

checkboxtree code

```
       <CheckboxTree    
                    nodes={listItems}
                    iconsClass="fa5"
                    checked={stateLod.checked}
                    data={classData}
                    onCheck={(checked) => 
                     stateLod.checked={checked}
                      } 
       />
```

Anyone have an idea to fix this one

also I tried this way.

```
function setCheckedNodes(checked){ 
    return true;
}

 <CheckboxTree    
  nodes={listItems}
  iconsClass="fa5"
  checked={stateLod.checked}
  data={classData}
  onCheck={(checked) => setCheckedNodes(checked)}
  } 
 />
```

Comment: You need to make your checked nodes a state.

Comment: can you explain more details @RoboRobok

Comment: I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to re-render the tree after toggling, you need to use state. The example code uses state in a class, while you seem to be using hooks, except you forgot to make checked items a state too:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function MyComponent() {
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState([]);

    return (
        <CheckboxTree
            nodes={listItems}
            iconsClass="fa5"
            checked={checked}
            data={classData}
            onCheck={setChecked}
        /> 
    );
}
```